# AngularFire2 (firestore) Need to set multiple docs at once like RealTime Database

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am switching from Firebases RealTime Database to Firestore. and there is a bit of a difference on how to add data

## my data

I have an object of products

```
const productsObj {
    products : [ {...},{...},{...},{...} ]
    meta: {}
}
```

## Firebase

my intended structure is...

**Collection**: `productsObj{}`

**Documents**: `productsObj.products` (several)

**Fields**: `productsObj.products[i].name`

## My Attempts

```
this.productCollection = this.afs.collection('products'); // compared to productsObj

this.productCollection.add(productsObj); // adds all products as one doc
this.productCollection.add(productsObj.products); // cant add array
this.productCollection.add(productsObj.products[0]); // works
```

the last one works but is that right? I would have to loop over several objects and call firebase for every new doc.

What is the best way to add all `productsObj.products` as documents, at one time?

**EDIT**
`productCollection` is declared like this `productCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<any>;`

Answer (score -1):

When you `add()` to a collection, you are creating a document with each call.

You want something like this:

```
productsObj.products.forEach( (project) => {
  this.productCollection.add(product);
};
```

See [AngularFire2 documentation on Adding Documents to a Collection](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#adding-documents-to-a-collection).

Comment: I understand. I want to know if making an post for every item in the list is good practice. Cause there are a lot of items. In realtime database we were able to add big json payloads all at once.

Comment: If you need to query on the products, each product will need to be a document in the collection, as queries are only available for collections. There is good guidance on [structuring data in Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data). Each document is limited to 1MB, so it is likely impractical to store a large number of products in one document, even if you don't need to query.

You can use a [Transaction or Batched Write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) to create all the documents reliably.

Comment: U miss understand. I have lots of Items from another database. and I need them all to be individual docs. I am looking for one Firebase method where i can add them all at once instead of "foreach item add doc one at a time"

Comment: very simply i need to `add multiple documents at once` like the title says

Comment: There is no import/export available in Firestore, as there was in RTDB. See: [How to import data to Cloud Firestore?](https://hackernoon.com/filling-cloud-firestore-with-data-3f67d26bd66e) for a simple example.